# Parse list inside a json in android

Tags: android, json

I am putting a list in the json and now I want to get the list and display   each entry in different textview. This is my code to put the list in json and to get the same

```
static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONObject json = jsonFruitArray.getJSONObject(i);
        list.add("john");
        list.add("mat");
        list.add("jason");
        json.put("sku",new JSONArray(list));
```

This is how i am trying to get the list

```
JSONArray jsonFruitSkuArray = json.getJSONArray("sku");
        for(int iSku=0; iSku< jsonFruitSkuArray.length();iSku++){
            JSONObject jsonSkuObject = jsonFruitSkuArray.getJSONObject(iSku);
            productBean.setSkuId1(jsonSkuObject.getInt("sku"));
        }
```

Comment: I want to fetch the values from the list and want to set in the setter.Dont know how to fetch multiple values with single key "sku in the above code"

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this. Use JsonArray

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("1", 1);
            jsonObject.put("2", 2);
            jsonObject.put("3", 3);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONArray result = new JSONArray();
        result.put(jsonObject);
```

Comment: i am able to put the values but unable to fetch it as i have only 1 key with 3 values so how to fetch value at 1 position and 2 & 3 as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use json array 

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

jsonArray.put("John");
jsonArray.put("Mat");
jsonArray.put("Jason");

jsonObj.put("json_array", jsonArray);

//Retrieve like this        

JSONArray jsonFruitSkuArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("json_array");
for(int iSku=0; iSku< jsonFruitSkuArray.length();iSku++){
    JSONObject jsonSkuObject = jsonFruitSkuArray.getJSONObject(iSku);
    productBean.setSkuId1(jsonSkuObject.getInt("sku"));
}
```

Comment: I want to display all the values in different textview, wont the above code will always store the last value in productBean.setSkuId1

Comment: If you have limited number of TextView then use Switch Case  to set your TextView.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you can try following :

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

list.add("john");
list.add("mat");
list.add("jason");

json.put("sku", new JSONArray(list));

JSONArray jsonFruitSkuArray = json.getJSONArray("sku");  

for (int iSku = 0; iSku < jsonFruitSkuArray.length(); iSku++) {
    String element = jsonFruitSkuArray.getString(iSku);
    System.out.println(element);
}
```